# Setting classpath enviroment variable value globally

Tags: java, classpath

I want to be able to execute a java class from Command Prompt in windows without specifying the classpath explicitly every time I want to execute a java class, for example like this

[image]

where I execute the HelloWorld class in the "ExamplePackage" package.

I want to accomplish the same result without specifying the classpath, as follows

[image]

but this gives me an `Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld`. As I understand it, this error is caused by java not being able to locate the class since classpath has not been specified.

Now, I want to solve this problem by setting a global variable classpath value to `C:\Users\UpdatusUser\Desktop\ExampleProject`.

This can be accomplished, as I understand, over here

[image]

But that does not seem to solve the issue, since I still get the following result if I now use `java ExamplePackage.HelloWorld`

[image]

---

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a full explanation see this:

[What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)

The short answer is execute the java command from the `ExampleProject` folder not the `ExamplePackage` folder.

Comment: I read that, that's where I got what I know thus far from. Any suggestions?

Comment: Execute the java command from the `ExampleProject` folder not the `ExamplePackage` folder.